# how can i fetch cart data from joomla session?

Tags: session, joomla2.5, session-variables, virtuemart

Hi I am working on a module where i have to fetch cart data from the session. For that I am use below mention code. I am able to fetch the data but all in one. Now my question is how do I get those data individually(product_id individually cart id individually etc)? Please guide me regarding this issue.

**Code**

```
$_data=unserialize($_SESSION['__vm']['vmcart']);
print_r($_data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution with help of below mentioned code

```
$cart = VirtueMartCart::getCart(); //getting cart object
$cmpny=$cart->BT; // accessing cart's elements
foreach($cmpny as $key =>$data)
{
  some usfull code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

did you check the vm cart module? your solution seams to be there.
try :

```
foreach ($_data->products as $product){
//var_dump($product);
echo $product->virtuemart_product_id.' || '.$product->product_name.' || '.$product->product_price;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply... but those data was not able to fetch from the vm cart module because all data are remain in session till user place the order.... but thanks for the help